# Exclusive OR Associativity Boolean Algebra Proof

Tags: boolean, xor, algebra

Prove `(A ⊕ B) ⊕ C = A ⊕ (B ⊕ C)` using boolean algebra.
I made the truth tables and found the sum of products, but couldnt figure how to show their equal.

I then tried doing

```
(a xor b) xor c  (a' - is NOT(A)/inverse)
(a'b + ab') ⊕ C
c' (a'b + ab') + c[(a'b + ab')']
```

Couldn't go from there,

Comment: Put both sides into disjunctive normal form.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`A^B` = `(AB'+A'B)`

`(AB)'` = `(A'+B')`

---

`(A^B)^C`

= `(AB'+A'B)C' + (AB'+A'B)'C`

= `(AB'C'+A'BC')+((AB')'(A'B)')C`

= `(AB'C'+A'BC')+(A'+B)(A+B')C`

= `(AB'C'+A'BC')+(A'(A+B')+B(A+B'))C`

= `(AB'C'+A'BC')+(A'B' + AB)C`

= `(AB'C'+A'BC'+A'B'C + ABC)`

= `A(B'C'+BC)+A'(BC'+B'C)`

= `A(B'C'+BC)+A'(B^C)`  (1)

`(B^C)'`

=`(BC'+B'C)'`

= `(BC')'(B'C)'`

= `(B'+C)(B+C')`

= `(B'C'+BC)` (2)

From `(2)`, the `(1)` = `A(BC'+B'C)' + A'(B^C)` = `A(B^C)' + A'(B^C)` = `A^(B^C)` #

Comment: Makes sense except for (B^C)', where does the negation of the B ^ C come from?

Comment: @Eric, look at `(1)`, now that we have A, we have A', we have (B^C), we need to find where is `(B^C)'`, it may be the `(B'C'+BC)`, but that is not very obvious, so why not just to expand `(B^C)'` to see what we'll get?

Answer (score 0):

Firstly define `XOR` and `XNOR`:

```
  A^B   = AB' + A'B     ... (1)
 (A^B)' = AB  + A'B'    ... (2)
```

Now expand `(A^B)C` using (1) and (2):

```
 (A^B)C = (A^B)C' + (A^B)'C
        = (AB' + A'B)C' + (AB + A'B')C
        = AB'C' + A'BC' + ABC + A'B'C
```

Collect terms and simplify:

```
        = A(B'C' + BC) + A'(BC' + B'C)
        = A(B^C)' + A'(B^C)
        = A^(B^C)
```

QED